# Error running hive script with parameters in parenthesis

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the code below saved in a file called tableCreate.hql.  I'm running it from the command line with

```
hive -f tableCreate.hql
```

I'm trying to use parameters but I keep getting error messages if there are parenthesis around the parameter like the example below.  I'm wondering do I need to add quotes.  I'm new to using parameters in hive scripts.

original code:

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;

set hivevar:MIN_DT=20170401;
set hivevar:MAX_DT=20170301;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT *
      FROM table t
      WHERE dt<=${MAX_DT} AND dt>=(${MIN_DT})
```

> error: unexpected symbol near ${MIN_DT}

modified code:

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;

set hivevar:MIN_DT=20170401;
set hivevar:MAX_DT=20170301;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT *
      FROM table t
      WHERE dt<=${MAX_DT} AND dt>=('${MIN_DT}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the namespace for variable substitution which is `hivevar` in this case.

```
WHERE dt<=${hivevar:MAX_DT} AND dt>=${hivevar:MIN_DT}
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I've run similar scripts with the old dt<=${MAX_DT} version, and had it complete.  What's the difference, using ${hivevar:MAX_DT} address the parenthesis issue?  For example what if I had a parameter that stored a list that I wanted to use in an in clase like: where dt in (${list_DT})